# Getting Java Exception subclass' getMessage() to work

Tags: java, exception, tostring

I'm trying to implement my first custom `RuntimeException`:

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean isFizz;
    private boolean isBuzz;
    private Widget widget;

    public class MyException(boolean isFizz, boolean isBuzz, Widget widget) {
        super();

        setIsFizz(isFizz);
        setIsBuzz(isBuzz);
        setWidget(widget);
    }

    // Getters and setters for all 3 properties...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("MyException is now in string form.");
    }
}
```

When I go to test this out:

```
MyException exc = new MyException(false, true, new Widget());

System.out.println(exc.toString());
System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
```

I get:

```
MyException is now in string form.
null
```

So `getMessage()` isn't working. I would like both `toString()` and `getMessage()` to produce the same string, and I *thought* that `Throwable#getMessage()` simply returned `toString()`.

So I ask: *what's the "normal" way of overriding `getMessage()`?* Do I literally have to just override it like `toString()`, like so:

```
@Override
public String getMessage() {
    return toString();
}
```

Or is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I *thought* that `Throwable#getMessage()` simply returned `toString()`.

You've got it the wrong way round.  `getMessage()` returns whatever message was passed to the superclass constructor:

```
 public MyException(boolean isFizz, boolean isBuzz, Widget widget) {
    super("This is the message");
```

and the default implementation of `toString()` returns the exception class name followed by the message.

Comment: Can I leave my `toString()` as-is, and then call it from the super ctor: `super(toString())`?

Comment: @TicketMonster No, Java won't let you call an instance method before the superclass constructor.  You could create a static method that both `toString()` and the constructor call into, passing in the `isFizz` and `isBuzz` values or whatever it needs.

Comment: I ask because my `toString()` is actually a lot more in-depth than what I put in the question...

Comment: So in that case, what can I do to make toString and getMessage return the same string?

Comment: @TicketMonster If there's no way to calculate the appropriate string up-front and pass it to `super()` then you'll just have to override `getMessage()` and have it call `toString()`.  But is there a particular reason _why_ you need them both to return the same thing?

Comment: ^^ `toString()` and `getMessage()` are *two different things*; they aren't meant to return the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't *set* a message, therefore `getMessage()` is most certainly going to return `null`.

In your constructor you're calling the no-arg constructor of `RuntimeException` via `super()` ... you would need to call `super(message)` (or one of the other two constructors that takes a message) and provide a message.

Comment: Thanks (+1) - please see my question under Ian Roberts' answer - I have the same question for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the message to your parent `Exception` class in the constructor, e.g.

```
public class MyException(boolean isFizz, boolean isBuzz, Widget widget) {     
 super("MyException is now in string form.");

}
```

Comment: Thanks (+1) - please see my question under Ian Roberts' answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: You can **not** refer to instance method when you are calling your `super` constructor. It is the same reason that `super` call, must be the first method in your constructor. By passing `toString()` as if you are calling `toString()` first then you call `super()` which is not allowed in Java